# Run time Error- c project

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

i make a function to print an BTree in level order none recursive way.

and i have a problem to find my mistake.. the following problem showing up.

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'pq' was corrupted.
 if some one can tell where is the problem is, or how i can find it by my self next time...?
i add the full project if is needed.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/alexzele/Matala.git)

```
void PrintTreeLevelOrder(bstree tree){      //The problem some where here.....
    queue *pq = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue)); // is struct of : *front, *rear

    node *current;// is struct of : root
     create_queue(&pq);//create queue- items_num = 0,front = NULL,rear = NULL

     if (tree.root == NULL) {
         printf("Your Tree Is Empty:\n");
         return;
     }
    current = tree.root;
    enqueue(current, &pq); 
    printf("Your Tree Displayed As Queue:\n");
    while ((size_of_queue(&pq) )!=0) {
        current = pq->front;
        printf("%d ", current->data);
        if (current->left != NULL) 
            enqueue(current->left, &pq);

        if (current->right) 
            enqueue(current->right, &pq);
            dequeue(&pq, &current);

    }

}
```

Comment: You're overwriting memory somehow, however all of the functions where you might do so aren't present in your example.

Comment: Please make a [MCVE] (emphasis on __minimal__).

Comment: I add a link to all the functions and the data structure...

Comment: Pump up the compiler's warning level. Take the compiler's warning serious and fix the code until no more warnings are issued. Do *not* blindly "cast away" warnings!

Comment: For starters: This `create_queue(&pq);` doesn't look nice. I am pretty sure the compiler warned you about this. Same here: `size_of_queue(&pq)`

Comment: And: There Is No Need To Cast `void`-Pointers In C.

Comment: No warrings at all. I tell you more, the function is working and printing on the screen the output...but after she finishes and exit from the while loop it giving the following mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to say that your algorithm is correct, please read the below.

Your code has multiple mistakes that should take care of

- You used the pq functions in a wrong way, you passed a pointer to a pointer instead of the original pointer, so you overwrote the code
- Create_queue should allocate unless you call it init but that's not the main issue
- You should check if create_queue succeeded
- You are saving addresses in the queue which are queue* as int which is wrong and not portable for an architecture different than 32bit
- you are assigning current which is a node (node tree struct) a queue_element element pointer struct, which is also not correct because they are different types and architectures

Please work on these points, if you want more details please contact me
I would be happy to help